# Recursively add identical element to each object in array

Tags: javascript

I have this Object contain array of object ('pages')

```
var obj = {
    "pages" : [
        {   
            "title": "title one",
            "sub" : [
                { "title" : "title one one"},
                { "title" : "title one two"}
            ]
        },
        { "title" : "title two" },
        { 
            "title" : "title three",
            "sub" : [
                { "title" : "title three one"},
                { "title" : "title three two"},
                { "title" : "title three three"}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and expected result like this (add 'slug' element to each object in 'pages')

```
{
    "pages" : [
        {
            "title" : "title one",
            "slug" : "title-one",
            "sub" : [ 
                {
                    "title" : "title one one",
                    "slug" : "title-one-one"
                },
                {
                    "title" : "title one two",
                    "slug" : "title-one-two"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title" : "title two",
            "slug" : "title-two"
        },
        {
            "title" : "title three",
            "slug"  : "title-three",
            "sub" : [
                {
                    "title" : "title three one",
                    "slug" : "title-three-one"
                },
                {
                    "title" : "title three two",
                    "slug" : "title-three-two"
                },
                {
                    "title" : "title three three",
                    "slug" : "title-three-three"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I guess I can do it like

```
function add_slug(array_of_obj)
{
    for (var item in array_of_obj) {

        //i am not sure about this:
        item.slug = item.title.replace(/ /g, '-');

        if(typeof item.sub !== undefined) {
            add_slug(item.sub);
        }
    }
}

add_slug(obj.pages);
```

But I get `undefined item.title` I keep modifying the function but it doesn't work yet so I need help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed to use for loop rather than for-in - safer for an array.

Try this:

```
function add_slug(array_of_obj)
{
    for(var pageIdx = 0; pageIdx < array_of_obj.length; ++pageIdx) {
        var curPage = array_of_obj[pageIdx];

        if(curPage.title) {
            curPage.slug = curPage.title.split(' ').join('-');
        }

        if(curPage.sub) {
            add_slug(curPage.sub);
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
{
  "pages": [
    {
      "title": "title one",
      "sub": [
        {
          "title": "title one one",
          "slug": "title-one-one"
        },
        {
          "title": "title one two",
          "slug": "title-one-two"
        }
      ],
      "slug": "title-one"
    },
    {
      "title": "title two",
      "slug": "title-two"
    },
    {
      "title": "title three",
      "sub": [
        {
          "title": "title three one",
          "slug": "title-three-one"
        },
        {
          "title": "title three two",
          "slug": "title-three-two"
        },
        {
          "title": "title three three",
          "slug": "title-three-three"
        }
      ],
      "slug": "title-three"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`item` is a string representing the current property of the object. What you need to do is use `item` to get the property from the object.

```
array_of_obj[item].slug = array_of_obj[item].title.replace(/ /g, '-');

if(array_of_obj[item].sub !== undefined) {
    add_item(array_of_obj[item].sub);
}
```

So the error was due to the fact that the `item` string doesn't have a `title` property, and so it's `undefined`, making the call to `.replace()` impossible.

---

Also, you were using `typeof` incorrectly when testing for `undefined`. It's better to just do a comparison without using `typeof`.

Also, your recursive call was using `add_item` instead of `add_slug`.

---

Last of all, it's better in JavaScript to use a `for` loop on an Array instead of a `for-in` loop. There are a few reasons for this. In your specific case, it may not make a difference, but it's still overall a better practice.

So your final function would look like this:

```
function add_slug(array_of_obj)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < array_of_obj.length; i++) {

        array_of_obj[i].slug = array_of_obj[i].title.replace(/ /g, '-');

        if(array_of_obj[i].sub !== undefined) {
            add_slug(array_of_obj[i].sub);
        }
    }
}

 add_slug(obj.pages);
```

---

Or using ES5 features, like this:

```
function add_slug(array_of_obj)
{
    array_of_obj.forEach(function(item) {

        item.slug = item.title.replace(/ /g, '-');

        if(item.sub !== undefined) {
            add_slug(item.sub);
        }
    }); 
}

 add_slug(obj.pages);
```

---

Or a different approach could look like this:

```
function add_slug(item) {

    item.slug = item.title.replace(/ /g, '-');

    if(item.sub !== undefined) {
        item.sub.forEach(add_slug);
    }
}

obj.pages.forEach(add_slug);
```

Or this:

```
obj.pages.forEach(function add_slug(item) {

    item.slug = item.title.replace(/ /g, '-');

    if(item.sub !== undefined) {
        item.sub.forEach(add_slug);
    }
});
```